# Angular 9.1.9 conditional routing with parameter

Tags: angular

**Context:**

I have a back and continue button that walk through stages and their child steps in a wizard.

**Question:**

I have the following routing:

```
{
    path: 'test/stage/1',
    component: WizardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'step/1',
        component: Stage1Step1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'step/2',
        component: Stage1Step2Component,
      }   
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'test/stage/2',
    component: WizardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'step/1',
        component: Stage2Step1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'step/2',
        component: Stage2Step2Component,
      }   
    ]
  },
```

the issue is that I want the components that are loaded by the various urls, to be very specific components, ergo I would like to avoid sharing a StepComponent as each route is doing a very particular task.

I need to say:

if stage 1, load x set of steps
but
if stage 2,  load y set of steps.

The problem I am having is that when I get to stage/2/step/1 it loads the WizardComponent again and I would like to avoid this.

Is there a nice way of having

```
test/stage/:stage
```

while also having some conditional choice of which children to use?

**Perhaps something like this?**

```
{
    path: 'test/stage/:stage',
    component: WizardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '1/step/1',
        component: Stage1Step1Component,
      },
      {
        path: '1/step/2',
        component: Stage1Step2Component,
      }   
      {
        path: '2/step/1',
        component: Stage2Step1Component,
      },
      {
        path: '2/step/2',
        component: Stage2Step2Component,
      }   
    ]
  }
```

(The above doesn't work)

Comment: What improvements do I need to make to avoid closure? I'm happy to add them

Comment: Try using lazy loading https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, it's really simple:

I just needed to do this instead:

```
{
    path: 'test',
    component: WizardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'stage/1/step/1',
        component: Stage1Step1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'stage/1/step/2',
        component: Stage1Step2Component,
      }   
      {
        path: 'stage/2/step/1',
        component: Stage2Step1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'stage/2/step/2',
        component: Stage2Step2Component,
      }   
    ]
  }
```

Although I will investigate the lazy loading module thing later as clearly this isn't very pretty to need to do this for knowing which stage and step i'm on for entry point to url:

```
// This is wrong and horrible, but can't figure out another way yet. Perhaps lazyprovider in the route?
let stageNumber = parseInt(window.location.pathname.split("/")[3]) // parseInt(this.route.parent.snapshot.url[2].path);
let stepNumber = parseInt(window.location.pathname.split("/")[5]) // parseInt(this.route.parent.snapshot.url[4].path);
```